# Get value from dropdown menu & display it on textfield in Bootstrap CSS

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to build a dropdown menu in which when I select a value from its list, I show this value in a text field next to it. I use Bootstrap CSS and JQUERY for this purpose.

This is what I have:

```
<div class="input-group">
   <div class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Select Shape File
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
     <?php foreach(glob("RunPythonThroughPHP/marCO/src/aa_scratch0/*.shp") as $filename) {
        // GET INDEX
        $pos = strpos($filename, 'aa_scratch0/');
        // GET SUBSTRING WITH SHAPE NAME
        $rest = substr($filename, $pos+12);
        echo "<li id='demolist'><a href=>".$rest."</a></li>";    
       }
        ?>
        </ul>
        </div><!-- /btn-group -->
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputShp" placeholder="Shape File Path" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Shape file path">        
        </div><!-- /input-group -->
<script>    

    $('#demolist').on('click', function(){
        $('#inputShp').val($(this).text());
    });

</script>
```

The problem is the following: when I click the value on the drop-down menu it appears in the textfield but it disappears instantly. Why does this happen?

Comment: Instead of `click` use `onchange` event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `onChange` and `.val()`:

```
$('#demolist').on('change', function(){
    $('#inputShp').val($(this).val());
});
```

Or in case of dropdown menu, use:

```
$('#demolist').on('click', function(){
    $('#inputShp').val($(this).find("a").text());
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I see the problem now. It seems when I select a value from the dropdown menu the page refreshes.

Comment: I wonder why this happens. Is it cause I populate my dropdown menu with a php script?

Comment: You need to send a `return false;` inside your function to stop navigating to the page.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Something that simple and I couldn't figure it out! I was thinking of building everything from scratch using <option> element.. Thanks.